# Use functions in Telerik MVC Grid filter? ("Expected token" exception)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

In the project I'm currently developing I'm using Telerik to handle the UI components.
I have to use client filtering in my current project; with "normal" expressions like: "PK_Random~eq~value" the filter works like a charm, but when I use the substring / startswith / endswith methods the debugger spit me a filterParserException with the "Expected Token" error, this is the JS code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function filter() {
        var grid = $("#gridID").data("tGrid");
        grid.filter("substringof(someName, 'Somevalue')");
    };
</script>
```

I call this function with an onlick event binded to a button. 
The model passed to the grid is created from a view in the db. 
The telerik's version I'm using is: 2011.3.1115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the space, it should work:

```
grid.filter("substringof(someName,'Somevalue')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It seems that the syntax `function(property, 'value')`
is not correct (even if it is described in the Telerik's userguide).

The correct syntax is similar to the other filters so `property~function~'value'`